# Copy results of joined query into identical table in other database

Tags: sql

I am trying to take the results of a select query in SQL and place them in another table in a different database. The table structure is identical. The select query is as follows;

```
USE Warwick
Go

Select   tblOperations.Link, Project.*

From     tblOperations

    Inner Join  Warwick.dbo.Project 

        On tblOperations.Link= Warwick.dbo.Project.[Project ID]

    Where tblOperations.Job# = Warwick.dbo.Project.[Job Number] and
    tblOperations.[Status] = 'Active' or tblOperations.[Status] = 'Pending'
```

The join lets me select just the jobs that are considered active. I need to copy the results into the table WCI_DB.dbo.Project, which already exists. I would lke to append and not overwrite if the record exists.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: <table_to_insert_into>'s structure is link, project_field_1, project_field_2, ..., project_field_n?

Comment: Ah.. No, the Link field comes from the joined table. It is used to pull the active jobs. The structure of the target table is identical to the source table. There are a LOT of fileds though. I was hoping to wild card them as opposed to having to list them all out. Is that possible?

Comment: Please consider table aliases in your queries.  They make the queries much more readable.  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should tag your question with the database, which seems to be SQL Server.  The SQL syntax is `insert`:

```
insert into WCI_DB.dbo.Project
    <your select here>;
```

Normally, you want to list columns after the table name:

```
insert into WCI_DB.dbo.Project(list of columns>
    <your select here>;
```

However, if this is a one-time exercise and you know the columns are the same, then it is small sin to omit them once.

To create a new table, using `select into`, which is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

```
select . . .
into WCI_DB.dbo.Project
. . .
```

Comment: That did it. thanks. I will take all suggestions here on board also.